# Does a WPF app in the new Microsoft Store require signing?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-signing

Microsoft is rolling out the new store [that accepts MSI/EXE apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/msiexe/overview). I've been granted access for my new WPF app.

I'm new to WPF dev and struggling with what I should be doing in terms of signing my App.

Since the app will be reviewed by MS and ultimately be installed via Microsoft Store, do I even need to sign it? If I do need to sign it (or should), is it enough to sign my app with my own created certificate?

I'm not particularly keen on buying code signing certificates for an app that I think will have limited revenue so looking for a way out if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted MS support and they responded with:

> We have received clarification on your question regarding the Win32 signing. Microsoft does not require a signature for EXE/MSI submissions at this time. We also cannot provide guidance on how you might sign your app if you choose to. In general, signatures from recognized authorities are considered more secure and are therefore preferred.